# Where to buy the best tour to Neuschwanstein castle?

Tags: transportation, germany, castles, bavaria, munich

We are going to visit [Neuschwanstein castle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neuschwanstein_Castle) in September. And can`t choose the tour agent to buy this day tour from Munich. Did anybody take such tour from Munich and can recommend us what to choose? Or is it better to get there by public transport?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by 'best'?  Each person's definition is different - do you mean cheaper, shorter, longer, most included extras (like champagne lunch, for example)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We had a look at public transport versus a tour for our visit and came to the conclusion that while it may cost somewhat more, the convenience of a tour from Munich outweighed the money saved.

[Grey Line](http://www.grayline.com/Munich/Neuschwanstein_Linderhof_German_Castle_Tour_Day_Trip_from_Munich) was the company that we did it with, because they were the only one running when we were in Munich (February).  They were perfectly adequate if you're not the type of person who runs screaming from group tours.  They include [Linderhof Palace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linderhof_Palace) as part of the tour.

The other option we looked at that looked more interesting and fun was [Mike's Bike Tours](http://www.mikesbiketours.com/munich/Castle-Tours/neuschwanstein-castle-tours-bus-bavaria.html), but unfortunately that was not running when we were in Munich.

Personally I'd do Mike's as it's cheaper, but skip the biking part and instead do [Hohenschwangau Castle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hohenschwangau_Castle) in addition to Neuschwanstein:

> For our guests NOT interested in the bike ride and other activities offered we suggest taking the tour of Hohenschwangau castle, which is at the same location and highly recommendable.